# Yii2 Editable Widget custom attribute

Tags: php, yii2, widget

i am working with Yii2 and using `Editable Widget`

My code is below

```
Editable::widget([
                    'id' => 1,
                    'name' => 'assignTo',
                    'value' => 1,
                    'url' => 'url here',
                    'type' => 'select',
                    'mode' => 'inline',
                    'clientOptions' => [
                        'toggle' => 'dblclick',
                        'emptytext' => 'Unassigned',
                        'placement' => 'right',
                        'select2' => [
                            'width' => '124px'
                        ],
                        'source' => 1,
                        'value' => 1,
                    ],
                ]);
```

i want to add `custom attribute` on that generated html tag. i have tried as below but its throw error

```
Editable::widget([
                    'id' => 'assignTo_'.$todo->id,
                    'name' => 'assignTo',
                    'redirect_url' => 'custom_attriute', // this is custom attribute that i need
                    'class' => 'my own custom class', // this is custom attribute that i need
                    'value' => 1,
                    'url' => 'url here',
                    'type' => 'select',
                    'mode' => 'inline',
                    'clientOptions' => [
                        'toggle' => 'dblclick',
                        'emptytext' => 'Unassigned',
                        'placement' => 'right',
                        'select2' => [
                            'width' => '124px'
                        ],
                        'source' => 1,
                        'value' => 1,
                    ],
                ]);
```

and also i want to add my own class in the generated html i have tried same as above but its not working.

is there any way to make it possible what i want?

Comment: @topher , 2amigOS!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dosamigos\editable\Editable` extends `yii\widgets\InputWidget` which has an [`$options`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-widgets-inputwidget.html#$options-detail) variable that holds:

> The HTML attributes for the input tag.

```
Editable::widget([
    'id' => 'assignTo_'.$todo->id,
    'name' => 'assignTo',
    'options' => [
        'redirect_url' => 'custom_attriute', // this is custom attribute that i need
        'class' => 'my own custom class', // this is custom attribute that i need
    ],
    'value' => 1,
    'url' => 'url here',
    'type' => 'select',
    'mode' => 'inline',
    'clientOptions' => [
        'toggle' => 'dblclick',
        'emptytext' => 'Unassigned',
        'placement' => 'right',
        'select2' => [
            'width' => '124px'
        ],
        'source' => 1,
        'value' => 1,
    ],
]);
```